# type="button" the button will not display

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, stylesheet

i can't get the button to display.
    
when i use this the background on the emulator is yellow and nothing display not even the textbox or label.
i have tryide romive just the type="submit" and then it shows up a text box on the create user  when it should be a button. i need help guys.
heres the code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Category",FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
   <div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
   </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)          
    </div>           
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create user" />// this is the problem
  </div>
}
```

when i remove type="submit" all that display  but not button.
but when i have type="submit" the hole emulator is yellow nothing display.
i have even tryied use  too its just the type="submit" is the problem.

and here the css and script

```
<link href="../../../Content/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

sorry for my poor english.

Comment: ops sorry i forgot that class shouldn't be there.. sorry. it should be like this    <div >
    <input type="submit" value="Create user" />// this is the problem
  </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its **style issue:**
Use Firebug and inspect the element you can see its complete style traces. This will help you out finding CSS issue.

Comment: hi i got this on red text (b.prop is not a function) and an x mark. and its from jquery....min.js so what should i do?

Comment: is seam like jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js is the problem but when i removed it the page on mobil is so wierd. the header is  no background color and the foter 2 no border or anything.

Comment: thanks! with firebug i replace the script <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script> it's working perfect now. :)